# R how to detect first last name with different ID?

Tags: r, duplicates, detect

```
ID <- c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5)
Firstname <- c("A","B","B","C","C","C","D","A")
Lastname <- c("F","G","G","H","H","H","I","F")
df <- data.frame(ID,Firstname,Lastname)
```

I want to find A F who has ID no 1 and 5.
In my real data, it's a long list and there are some persons who use different ID no. with the same name. How would you find out the row index of these people? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for the `duplicated` function. Have you done any searching? (It appears not.) It's not hard to find worked examples.

Comment: I thought about `duplicated`, then I got A F(ID 1,5) and B G(ID 2). But I want to detect only A F (ID 1,5) because they have the same name with different IDs.  Do I need to set up more in the function?

Comment: I was thinking you could use `!duplicated(ID,Firstname,Lastname) & duplicated(Firstname,Lastname)`

Answer (score 1):

Getting the result as a list:

```
subset(aggregate(ID~Firstname + Lastname, unique(df), length), ID > 1)[1:2]

  Firstname Lastname
1         A        F
```